# Python for Data Analysis: Chp 2 Pg 38 "prop_cumsum" error

Tags: python, cumsum, prop

I'm working on this book and keep running error when i'm run "Prop_cumsum"

**> prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.cumsum()**

> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:1:
>   FutureWarning: by argument to sort_index is deprecated, pls use
>   .sort_values(by=...)   if **name** == '**main**':
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    1944             try:
>   -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    1946             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> KeyError: 'prop'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.cumsum()
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   sort_index(self, axis, level, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position,
>   sort_remaining, by)    3237                 raise ValueError("unable
>   to simultaneously sort by and level")    3238             return
>   self.sort_values(by, axis=axis, ascending=ascending,
>   -> 3239                                     inplace=inplace)    3240     3241         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
>   3149     3150             by = by[0]
>   -> 3151             k = self[by].values    3152             if k.ndim == 2:    3153
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)    1996         else:
>   -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)    1998     1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   _getitem_column(self, key)    2002         # get column    2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
>   -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)    2005     2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   _get_item_cache(self, item)    1348         res = cache.get(item)    1349         if res is None:
>   -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)    1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)    1352
>   cache[item] = res
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
>   in get(self, item, fastpath)    3288     3289             if not
>   isnull(item):
>   -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)    3291             else:    3292                 indexer =
>   np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    1945                 return
>   self._engine.get_loc(key)    1946             except KeyError:
>   -> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    1948     1949
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> KeyError: 'prop'

Comment: Please add more code to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: This is the code i tried 'prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.cumsum()'

Comment: This is found in page 38 of the Python for Data Analysis book

Comment: There is no errors in commands on pages 32-38 (including your command). Try to reproduce commands on pages 32-38 step-by-step. If you have newer version of pandas than author have used, read help for conflict functions and change names of parameters (in my case there have been conflicts in pivot_table function (parameters were renamed in this way: rows->index, cols->columns)). My version of pandas is 0.18.1.

Comment: Yeah, i did everything from pg 32-38 without any issues and changed the (row to indexs and cols to columns)
But i cant get pass this problem with the command above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you invoked `sort_index` instead of `sort_values`.  The `by='prop'` doesn't make sense in such a context (you sort the index by the index, not by columns in the data frame).

Also, in my early release copy of the 2nd edition, this appears near the top of page 43.  But since this is early release, the page numbers may be fluid.